# Blender Texture/Model Seam Problems

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, uv-image-editor

I am creating an old Greek pillar for practice but during the creation process there appears to be a seam that's being rendered in the texture and model. I have gone in to texture paint mode and tried using the clone, and smear tool to blend the textures, and while it will blend the actual texture together it does absolutely nothing to the seam.

I have also tried baking uvmap. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? Did I incorrectly unwrap the model? I have surfed the threads trying to find something to help me fix my issue but it seems everything I try does nothing to make this seam disappear.

[image: Image Cycles_Render]

[image: UVMAP]

[image: Node Editor Screenshot]

I have turned the bias down to zero, it yields a slightly better result but the seam is still visible. Should I be using an image editor to make the texture tile properly?

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue, and my solution was turning the bias to 0 before you bake the normal map.

Comment: @Akados 

I am still learning, is the bias option in the node editor, uv editor, mesh tab, render tab? I have not been able to find that option.

Comment: It's in the Render Properties, under the Bake settings. (Blender Render, then after the bake, switch back to Cycles if you're using Cycles)

Comment: -Make sure the left and right side of your texture map match.
-Run "Remove Doubles" on you mesh.
-Post your texture map here

Comment: I am using a uv map to tell the material nodes how to wrap, I thought the uv map was the texture map? Or are you referring to editing the uv map with the texture in like photoshop? I thought thats what a texture map was. If you can't tell I'm still trying to learn the texturing part of the modeling process, as far as the physical mesh goes thats pretty simple to me

Comment: The issue is not with the UVs or the seams. Your texture needs to be tileable or seamless. Read:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15085/how-can-a-texture-converted-to-be-tileable-seamless and 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71636/texturing-a-sphere-with-a-tiled-texture

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to leave some space (a few pixels at least) between your UV pieces. Then turn on `bleed` in texture paint mode and when you bake things, so your texture extends beyond the boundaries of your model's UV coordinates. Doing both these things will avoid interpolation issues at the seams. There may be more issues in your case, but this is the first thing I would do to get rid of the seams.

*`Bleed` for texture painting is located in the Tool shelf > Options > Project Paint > Bleed. Increase the value to say 8.
For baking, the same thing is called `Margin`. But again, for either of these to be effective, you must first add some space between your UV pieces.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I have been unable to find the "bleed" option in texture paint mode, can you be a bit more specific as to where it is located? A simple google search is not turning up the specific information I am looking for.

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, have you tried to blend all the textures or just the color (diffuse) texture? if so, try to blend the displacement instead, that might not be it, but that is something that you should check anyways because i would do that by accident myself.